# java StringJoiner

Tags: java, строки, java-stream

Для сборки текста мы использовали `StringJoiner`, или `StringBuilder`. Стримы также позволяют сложить элементы, если они являются строками, в единый текст. Для этого используется метод `collect()` и `Collectors.joining()`. Метод `joining()` принимает те же аргументы, что и `StringJoiner`

Ваша задача собрать строки списка в текст и добавить префикс "Prefix", и суффикc "Suffix"(т.е. нужно использовать перегруженный вариант `joining()`). Разделителем должен быть `System.lineSeparator()`

мой код:

```java
public class JoiningMethod {
    public static String join(List<String> strings) {
        return List.of(strings.toString())
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining("Prefix","Suffix"));
    }  
}
```

тест:

> ```
> public class JoiningMethodTest {
>
>     @Test
>     public void test() {
>         StringJoiner expect = new StringJoiner(
>                 System.lineSeparator(),
>                 "Prefix",
>                 "Suffix"
>         );
>         expect.add("A");
>         expect.add("B");
>         expect.add("C");
>         assertEquals(
>                 expect.toString(),
>                 JoiningMethod.join(List.of(
>                         "A", "B", "C"
>                 ))
>         );
>     } }
> ```

ошибка:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [[[A, B, C]]] but found [PrefixA
B
CSuffix]

    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
    at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:512)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEqualsImpl(Assert.java:134)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:189)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:199)
    at ru.job4j.sentence.JoiningMethodTest.test(JoiningMethodTest.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

помогите пожалуйста правильно написать код для решения задания.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, класс `JoiningMethod` не компилируется, так как не существует реализации `Collectors.joining`, принимающей 2(два) строковых аргумента -- пропущен делимитер для строк `System.lineSeparator()`.

Также следует отметить, что в используемом варианте тестового фреймворка в методе `assertThat` первый аргумент - *тестируемое* значение (actual), а второй - *ожидаемое* (expected).

Во-вторых, метод `JoiningMethod.join` реализован некорректно: сначала входной список преобразуется в строку `"[A, B, C]"`, затем создается иммутабельный список, включающий эту единственную строку, и затем при помощи Stream API генерируется результат.  Поскольку строка одна, делимитер для строк не используется и добавляются только префикс и суффикс: `"Prefix[A, B, C]Suffix"`.

Если нужно реализовать так же, как в `StringJoiner`, не нужно превращать исходный список в строку:

```java
class JoiningMethod {
    public static String join(List<String> strings) {
        return strings
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(
                System.lineSeparator(), "Prefix", "Suffix"
            ));
    }  
}
```

В такой реализации результат будет аналогичный `StringJoiner`:

```
PrefixA
B
CSuffix
```

Comment: решение верно! Спасибо!